# java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key - java.security.InvalidKeyException: pad block corrupted

Tags: java, android, ssl, self-signed

I am trying to connect an android app to an XML web service under IIS over SSL (Self Signed SSL). I’ve followed below procedure:

1. creating a Self Signed Certificate under IIS Manager
2. export that certificate as a pfx file
3. then converting pfx to (java keystore) jks (PKCS12 format) as detailed below
4. embedding jks as a raw data in android app
5. and reading the content of jks file as follows

**Converting pfx to jks**

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore cert.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 
-destkeystore cert.jks -deststoretype pkcs12
```

**Reading the content of jks**

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
InputStream in = _context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);
try
{
    keyStore.load(in, "123456".toCharArray());
    mgrFact.init(keyStore, "123456".toCharArray());
}
catch (Throwable t)
{
    logger.error(t.getMessage());
}
finally
{
    in.close();
}
```

And now `keyStore.load` throws the following exception

```
java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key 
-java.security.InvalidKeyException: pad block corrupted
```

Where may I’ve made a mistake?

In fact, I followed what has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20658849/android-ksoap2-ssl-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexception)

Thanks

Comment: Why are you calling the destination keystore .jks when it is PKCS#12? This is only going to lead to confusion.

Comment: Did you managed to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is 4 years old, but just in case someone else get the same error:

I don't know why but there seem to be differences between the keystore generated with keytool of OpenJDK 11 and the one (with same certificates / keys / passwords) generated by keytool of Oracle JDK 8.

The problem for me arose using the `keystore-jdk11.p12` under

- Tomcat 8.5
- Oracle JVM 8 (u241)

I fixed this simply reimporting the content of the keystore generated with OpenJDK 11 with keytool of Oracle JDK 8, with

```sh
/path/of/jdk8.241/bin/keytool \
   -importkeystore \
   -srckeystore keystore-jdk11.p12 \
   -destkeystore keystore-jdk8.p12 \
   -deststoretype pkcs12
```